# Salted Password Hashing not validating correctly

Tags: c#, security

I am trying to implement some basic security for logins on a development website. I am using this code (C#) from https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

For some reason it just doesn't work, the password hash generated is stored in my DB exactly as generated, it just doesn't seem to work when I try to validate a password against the hash using ValidatePassword(string password, string correctHash)

The ValidatePassword is supposed to generate the same hash, but it doesn't.

Does anybody have any experience using this code, or have any code that actually works? I have tried several now, including the one on the MSDN and none seem to fit the bill. It is suggested I shouldn't try to write my own code to achieve this.

Here is my code that calls the method, I have validated during debugging that the inputs are correct.

I have copied the code from the linked website into a static helper class which is called by my service methods below.

```
    public ResultModel Register(string emailAddress, string password, string givenName, string familyName)
    {
        var _db = new EntityConnection();

        if (_db.Users.Any(x => x.isDeleted == false && x.EmailAddress == emailAddress))
            return new ResultModel() { success = false, message = "Email Address already registered, please attempt to Login" };

        password = HashHelper.CreateHash(password);

        var user = new User()
        {
            EmailAddress = emailAddress,
            Password = password,
            GivenName = givenName,
            FamilyName = familyName,
            DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
            isDeleted = false,
            isApproved = false
        };

        _db.Users.Add(user);

        _db.SaveChanges();

        var activationToken = new Token()
        {
            TokenType = "Account Activation",
            User = user,
            UserID = user.UserID,
            DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
            TokenCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };

        _db.Tokens.Add(activationToken);

        _db.SaveChanges();

        return new ResultModel() { success = true, entity = user };
    }

    public ResultModel Login(string emailAddress, string password)
    {
        var _db = new EntityConnection();

        var user = _db.Users.Where(x => x.isDeleted == false && x.EmailAddress == emailAddress);

        if (!user.Any() || user.Count() > 1)
            return new ResultModel() { success = false, message = "Credentials supplied do not match an Account, please try again." };

        var existingHash = user.First().Password;

        var result = HashHelper.ValidatePassword(password, existingHash);

        if (result)
            return new ResultModel() { success = true, entity = user.First() };
        else
            return new ResultModel() { success = false, message = "Credentials supplied do not match an Account, please try again." };
    }
```

Comment: Given this is C#, I would recommend looking at one of the authentication providers bundled with ASP.Net rather than creating this yourself.  Security is a tricky thing to get right, and the news is full of sites that have been hacked.

Comment: The `CreateHash` isn't going to create the same hash twice. You need to store the created hash and validate with that one, not generate a new one. Otherwise two users with the same password would have the same hash, and thats a security hole.

Comment: @EricJ: sites that use bundled providers are hacked too. I mean, using or not using a bundled provider is not related to overall security. On the other hand, implemeting password storage with, say, bcrypt is straightforward and doesn't introduce any major risks.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Yes, but what is likely more secure?  A mainstream bundled provider with open source code that is examined by the community, or a roll-your-own security solution?